# VS2010 exception right when I start typing in .aspx file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, exception

I'm using Visual Studio 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel and I've just recently started having a problem with it. When I open a .aspx page to change any of the markup as soon as I start typing I get an error message that pops up that says

> "Visual Studio has encountered an exception. This may be caused by an extension."

It then tells me I can see more details about the error by using the /log trigger and then look at the ActivityLog.xml.  After the exception my intellisense doesn't work when I start typing

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException() at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index) at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1.System.Collections.Generic.IList.get_Item(Int32 index) at Artem.VisualStudio.Outlining.OutliningTagger.CalculateChange(TextContentChangedEventArgs e) at Artem.VisualStudio.Outlining.OutliningTagger.HandleBufferChanged(Object sender, TextContentChangedEventArgs e) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.RaiseEvent[TArgs](Object sender, EventHandler`1 eventHandlers, TArgs args)

and

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception. at Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IOleCommandTarget.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandChainNode.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.CommandFilterWrapper.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsTextViewAdapter.Exec(Guid& pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 nCmdID, UInt32 nCmdexecopt, IntPtr pvaIn, IntPtr pvaOut) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.SendCommand(Guid cmdGroup, UInt32 cmdID, Object inParam) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.VsKeyboardFilter.TextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs args) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.b_*0(KeyProcessor p, TextCompositionEventArgs args) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.Implementation.KeyProcessorDispatcher.<>c*_DisplayClass1e`1.b__1a() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object errorSource, Action call)

Under "Source" (in the ActivityLog.xml) they both say "Editor or Editor Extension".

I have tried disabling all the extension I have installed, but it doesn't make any difference.  I'm on a Win7 64bit machine.

There are some posts I've seen relating to fixing a registry entry, but my registry entry already looks exactly right.  I'm at a loss and I'm hoping someone has had a similar issue.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried launching devenv.exe with the /ResetSettings or /SafeMode  flag? ref: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xee0c8y7.aspx)

Comment: I have tried the /safemode switch, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.  I also just tried the /resetsettings switch and the problem remains. :-(  It was worth a shot!

Answer (score 0):

The extention causing the problem is right in your error message:

```
Artem.VisualStudio.Outlining.OutliningTagger
```

http://jsoutlining.codeplex.com/workitem/29965 Related?

Comment: That could very well be related. It sounds like the same issue and I did install a plugin for jsoutlining.  I also disabled and then uninstalled it, but the issue still remains. The only extension I have installed right now is the Enterprise Library, but that has worked great since it was installed.

Comment: Could you have a physical look into the {VS2010_INSTALL_DIR}\Common7\IDE\Extensions folder? just to be sure :D

Comment: Looks ok in the physical folder. :-)

Comment: But it clearly is still loaded in VS somehow as the code gets executed :/